# In Extjs, how to call a a function in a view from another controller?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am trying to get this to work in [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home). The problem I am facing is that I get an error on this line

```
MyApp.app.getView('MyApp.view.test2').test();
```

When you click inside the textbox, it fails with an error (in console log) Uncaught TypeError: MyApp.app.getView(...).test is not a function

```
//Controller
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.test',
    myVar:0,
    init: function() {
    }
});

//View
Ext.define('MyApp.view.test', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    alias:'widget.test',
    controller: 'test',
    title: 'Hello',   
    listeners: {
        focus: function(comp){
            MyApp.app.getView('MyApp.view.test2').test(); //Fails with an error that test is not a function                        }
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

//View
Ext.define('MyApp.view.test2', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias:'widget.test2', 
    title: 'Hello2',     
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    test:function()
    {
        alert('in MyApp.view.test2');
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.test');
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.test2');
    }
});
```

Comment: You're getting the view, not the controller.  Something like this, maybe? `MyApp.app.getView('MyApp.view.test2').controller.test();`

Comment: What you are trying to do is called *tight coupling* which is bad practice and certainly not what MVVC is intended for. Use events / unobtrusive binding.

Comment: Besides that, your logic should be in a controller. Your view should only be responsible for presentation. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/application_architecture.html

Answer (score 2):

The `getView()` function just returns the **class** and **not the instance of the view**. See [ExtJs 5.1.1 Controller.getView()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-getView) :

> Returns a View class with the given name. To create an instance of the view, you can use it like it's used by Application to create the Viewport:
>
> `this.getView('Viewport').create();`

To get the created view instance you can archive it with a [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query).

```
//query returns an array of matching components, we choose the one and only
var test2View = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('test2')[0];
// and now we can execute the function
test2View.test();
```

See the running minimalistic [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/t0g).

```
//View
Ext.define('MyApp.view.test', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    alias: 'widget.test',
    title: 'Hello',
    listeners: {
        focus: function (comp) {
            //query returns an array of matching components, we choose the one and only
            var test2View = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('test2')[0]; 
            test2View.test();
            //MyApp.app.getView('MyApp.view.test2').test();//Fails with an error that test is not a function
        }
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});


//View
Ext.define('MyApp.view.test2', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.test2',
    title: 'Hello2',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    test: function ()
    {
        alert('in MyApp.view.test2');
    }
});


Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.test');
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.test2');
    }
});
```